# Hardhat test error, "TypeError: ABI not iterable" when running npx hardhat test

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x

I am not sure where I am going wrong, but I think it is within my `const [owner, _] = ...`
area.  I could be wrong, but I am not sure where, if anywhere I should be putting another argument, or inserting the abi string somewhere.

My `test.js` file:

```js
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {expect} = require("chai");

describe("BCCasino tests", () => {
    let token20, token721, token1155, casino;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        
        const Token20 = await ethers.getContractFactory();
        const Token721 = await ethers.getContractFactory();
        const Token1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory();

        const ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");

        token20 = await Token20.deploy();
        token721 = await Token721.deploy();
        token1155 = await Token1155.deploy();

        await token20.deployed();
        await token721.deployed();  
        await token1155.deployed();

        casino = await CasinoFactory.deploy(
            token20.address, 
            token721.address,
            token1155.address
        );

        await casino.deployed();
    
    });

    it("..should deploy correctly", async () => {
        //const parsedABI = JSON.parse("BCCasino");
        const [owner, _]= await ethers.getSigners();

        expect(await casino.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
        expect(await casino.token20()).to.equal(token20.address);
        expect(await casino.token721()).to.equal(token721.address);
        expect(await casino.token1155()).to.equal(token1155.address);

        
    });
});
```

here is the `.sol` file:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

import "./BC1155.sol";
import "./BCNFT.sol";
import "./BCToken.sol";
import "./AccessControl.sol";


contract BCCasino is AccessControl {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    BC1155 public token1155;
    BCNFT public token721;
    BCToken public token20;

    Counters.Counter public machineIdCounter;

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public machineToAmount;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public deposits;  //user --> machine -->  amount

    event Deposit(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 indexed machine,
        uint256 amount
    );

    event Reward(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 indexed rewardType,
        uint256 amount
    );

    constructor(address _token20, address _token721, address _token1155) {
        token20 = BCToken(_token20);
        token721 = BCNFT(_token721);
        token1155 = BC1155(_token1155);
    }
    function addMachine(uint256 amount) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
        require(amount > 0, "Invalid amount");
        uint256 machineId = machineIdCounter.current();
        machineToAmount[machineId] = amount;
        machineIdCounter.increment();
        return true;
    }

    function deposit(uint256 machineId) external returns(bool) {
        require(machineId <= machineIdCounter.current(), "Invalid Machine ID");
        address user = msg.sender;
        uint256 amount = machineToAmount[machineId];
        token20.transferFrom(user, address(this), amount);
        deposits[user][machineId] += amount;
        emit Deposit(user, machineId, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function reward(address user, 
                    uint256 amount, 
                    uint256 rewardType, 
                    uint256 machineId
    ) external onlyAdmin returns(bool) {
        require(rewardType < 3, "Invalid reward Type");
        require(
            deposits[user][machineId] >= machineToAmount[machineId],
            "User didn't make a deposit for the game. Invalid request"
        );

        deposits[user][machineId] -= machineToAmount[machineId];

        if(rewardType == 2) {
            token721.mint(user);
            emit Reward(user, 2, 1);
         } else if (rewardType == 1){
            token1155.mint(user, 1);
            emit Reward(user, 1, 1);
         } else {
            token20.mint(user, amount);
            emit Reward(user, 0, amount);
         }

         return true;
        }

    function totalMachine() external view returns(uint256) {
        return machineIdCounter.current();
    }
    }
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```shell
 BCCasino tests
       "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":
     TypeError: abi is not iterable
      at addGasToAbiMethodsIfNecessary (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:409:28)
      at getContractFactoryByAbiAndBytecode (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:288:27)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\BCCasino.test.js:9:25)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

I fixed my code and inserted the string ABIs in the deploy statements, as suggested but now I get this error when I try to test.

```shell
  1) BCCasino tests
       "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":
     Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at Logger.checkArgumentCount (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:340:18)
      at ContractFactory.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:1237:16)
      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
      at C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
      at ContractFactory.deploy (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:1138:16)
```

here is updated `test.js` file.

```js
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");
const {expect} = require("chai");

describe("BCCasino tests", () => {
    let token20, token721, token1155, casino;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        
        const Token20 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCToken");
        const Token721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCNFT");
        const Token1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BC1155");
        const CasinoFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");  

        

        token20 = await Token20.deploy();
        token721 = await Token721.deploy();
        token1155 = await Token1155.deploy();

        await token20.deployed();
        await token721.deployed();  
        await token1155.deployed();

        casino = await CasinoFactory.deploy(
            token20.address, 
            token721.address,
            token1155.address
        );

        await casino.deployed();
    
    });

    it("..should deploy correctly", async () => {
        //const parsedABI = JSON.parse("BCCasino");
        const [owner, _]= await ethers.getSigners();

        expect(await casino.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
        expect(await casino.token20()).to.equal(token20.address);
        expect(await casino.token721()).to.equal(token721.address);
        expect(await casino.token1155()).to.equal(token1155.address);

        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the contract name to the `getContractFactory` thats why you have the error, you just have to provide the name of the contract you want to deploy with that factory.

here is your updated `test.js` file

```
const Token20 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCToken");
const Token721 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCNFT");
const Token1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("BC1155");
const CasinoFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("BCCasino");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did that and now I am getting the following error message...........

  "before each" hook for "..should deploy correctly":     
     Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

for the error, `Error: missing argument: in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)` you need to pass in a constructor in the test cos there is a constructor in you .sol code

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when traying to call methods from a smart contract, getting this error.

```
for (const a of abi) {
                        ^

TypeError: abi is not iterable
```

the solution was simple, when you deploy your contract, the abi is save in the artifacts folder *root/artifacts/contractName.sol/contractName.json*

the abi should be a list of objets, not at object, so the default abi looks like this.

```
{
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "coinRoll",
  "sourceName": "contracts/coinroll.sol",
  "abi": [
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "amountCantBeZero",
      "type": "error"
    },
     //rest of the abi ///
  ],
  "bytecode": “0x60806///",
  "linkReferences": {},
  "deployedLinkReferences": {}
}
```

so just stay with the value of the key abi like so.

```
[
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "amountCantBeZero",
      "type": "error"
    },
     //rest of the abi ///
  ]
```

that should fix the problem