# TypeError in deploy.js file

Tags: solidity

I am getting an error after typing "node deploy.js" in the terminal : `TypeError: abi is not iterable`

Here is the exact error code :

```
TypeError: abi is not iterable
    at new Interface (/home/matrix/Blockchain/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/interface.js:251:25)
    at Interface.from (/home/matrix/Blockchain/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/interface.js:1100:16)
    at new ContractFactory (/home/matrix/Blockchain/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/factory.js:34:44)
    at main (/home/matrix/Blockchain/deploy.js:25:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/matrix/Blockchain/deploy.js:32:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
```

My code is :-

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  // Our Native Blockchain is being used by the ganache application
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545

  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
  //Private keys should not be kept open like this there are some alternatives that we will se in he future
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x1dcfb8a90efb060b6b1dade3d7d2794e12df4e7d040963a8d42bb5be05241926",
    provider
  );

  const abi = new fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
    "utf8"
  );

  const binary = new fs.readFileSync(
    "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );

  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying Please wait..........");
  // Await can only be used in async(asynchronous function)
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); // Hey Wait here, the the contract deploy first
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I tried many options, I even used ChatGPT but it did not helped.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/150882/hardhat-test-error-typeerror-abi-not-iterable-when-running-npx-hardhat-test